# MySQL Group Counting for Percentage

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

Here is my data:

```
BadgeID | Session | Session Type | My_Interest_Area | 
___________________________________________
12345   | PG1     | Symposium    | COPD
12345   | PG1     | Symposium    | Asthma
12345   | PG2     | Symposium    | COPD
12345   | PG2     | Symposium    | Asthma
12345   | PG3     | Workshop     | COPD
12345   | PG3     | Workshop     | Asthma
54321   | PG1     | Symposium    | ARDS
54321   | PG1     | Symposium    | Asthma
```

I am attempting to get this result:

```
Interest Area | Symposium Count| Workshop Count
____________________________________
COPD          | 1              | 1
Asthma        | 2              | 1
ARDS          | 1              | 0
```

Initially, I was thinking use a Where Clause and separate each Session Type:

```
select CDS_Interest_Areas as "Interest Area", round(COUNT(DISTINCT(BadgeID))/count(BadgeID)*100,0) as "Percent" from interest_areas_dataset where CDS_Interest_Areas IS NOT null and `Session Type` = "Symposium"
group by CDS_Interest_Areas
```

Using the Where Clause is not required for me.
I'd just like to get the results.

Also, I'd like to get percentages. The percent said 'Interest Area' makes up said 'Session Type'.

Example:
Symposium has 10% Asthma, 5% COPD, etc...

Comment: Btw, this is a much clearer way of asking your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `conditional aggregation` along with `distinct` to get your expected results:

```
select My_Interest_Area,
   count(distinct (case when `Session Type` = 'Symposium' then badgeid end)) SymposiumCount,
   count(distinct (case when `Session Type` = 'Workshop' then badgeid end)) WorkshopCount
from interest_areas_dataset 
group by My_Interest_Area
```

- [Sample Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tocVQVg2LrmVt7C3hbEgK3/0)

Comment: Why use 'Then badgeid'? what does that do? Also, can I get a percentage by using count(distinct (case when `Session Type` = 'Symposium' then badgeid end))/100  ??

Comment: @MichaelClayton - this is called `conditional aggregation`.  basically count all distinct badgeids that match that case condition.  your previous question reminded me you wanted distinct badges, if not, asthma would return 3 symposiums for example.  In regards to percentages, you can definitely get one, but as in your previous question, I'm unsure what exact percentage you are looking for.  If you edit your question with the expected percentage results, it would be more clear.

Comment: ahh, I see the connection between 'distinct' and 'then badge'. Thanks, I edited the question too.